# How can I configure an xmpp room using swift 4, (robbiehanson xmppframework), to allow membership and passwords

Tags: swift, xmppframework

Goal: configure xmpp room to restrict access to members only, then add members. using xmppframework in swift4

there is some documentation on the xmppframework github but it is generally in objective c and aimed at people that know what they're doing

I am creating a little program that logs into my xmpp server4, then joins a room, and starts posting alerts based on my staff productivity. 
I have created the room, and it has a history, and i can post to the room fine. 
I want to restrict the room so that only certain users can join

```
 func xmppStreamDidAuthenticate(_ sender: XMPPStream) {
 self.xmppStream.send(XMPPPresence())
 print("Connected, and Authenticated")

 // Join Room
 let roomStorage: XMPPRoomMemoryStorage = XMPPRoomMemoryStorage()
 let roomJID = XMPPJID(string: "chatalerts@muc.im.taudy.com") ?? 
 XMPPJID(string: "chatalerts@muc.im.taudy.com")

 let xmppRoom: XMPPRoom = XMPPRoom(roomStroage: roomStorage, jid: roomJID!, 
 dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
 xmppRoom.fetchConfigurationForm()
 }
```

I now need to configure the room,  i believe i am required to use

```
xmppRoom.configureRoom(usingOptions:XMLElement )
```

as a beginner programmer, I have no idea how to proceed, so I'm looking for an  example configuration of a room, restricted to members, in which I can add or remove members as required.

Comment: Hello there, I am also looking for way how to create group chat using xmpp framework , using swift language. Have you find way to create group chat? if yes, can u share link on github?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detail of [XMPP-MUC](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html) , and to restricting room for members only you can use this [XEP-0045](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#registrar-formtype-owner).

For restricting a room you may use following delegate.

```
func xmppRoom(_ sender: XMPPRoom, didFetchConfigurationForm configForm: DDXMLElement) {
    
    print("XMPPManager xmppRoom didFetch ConfigurationForm : \(configForm)")
    
    let newForm = configForm.copy() as! DDXMLElement
    
    let groupName = "Your Room Name"
    
    
    for field in newForm.elements(forName: "field")
    {
        
        if let _var = field.attributeStringValue(forName: "var")
        {
            
            switch _var
            {
            case "muc#roomconfig_persistentroom":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "1"))

            case "muc#roomconfig_roomname":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name : "value", stringValue :groupName))

            case "muc#roomconfig_publicroom":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "1"))

            case "muc#roomconfig_whois":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.insertChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "anyone"), at: 0)

            case "muc#roomconfig_allow_subscription":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "1"))

           // Here goes your value. in your case you have to send 1.
            case "muc#roomconfig_membersonly":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "1"))


            case "muc#roomconfig_getmemberlist":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "moderator"))
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "participant"))
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "visitor"))

            case "muc#roomconfig_moderatedroom":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "1"))

            case "public_list":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "1"))

            case "muc#roomconfig_allowinvites":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "1"))

            case "muc#roomconfig_changesubject":
                field.removeChild(at: 0)
                field.addChild(DDXMLElement(name: "value", stringValue: "true"))
                
            // other configures
            default:
                break
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    sender.configureRoom(usingOptions: newForm)
    
}
```